# Add class to this line... php/css

Tags: php, css

I have this line in php

```
<a title="'.htmlspecialchars($User->Name).'" href="'.$Href.'"'.$LinkClass.'>
```

I need to add another class which is known called tip

The code above generates something like this:

```
<a class="ProfileLink" href="/respond/profile/2/422" title="422">
```

As you can see $LinkClass gives me the class "ProfileLink" which is great

But I need to parse the class like "ProfileLink tip"

So just not sure how to amend $LinkClass above to something like $LinkClass tip

This is probably so basic I just cant see the wood for the trees

//

Edit: to add

Final html output needs to be :

```
<a class="ProfileLink tip" href="/respond/profile/2/422" title="422">
```

//

Added:

Entire php output for this function is:

```
  if (!function_exists('UserPhoto')) {
   function UserPhoto($User, $Options = array()) {
    $User = (object)$User;
  if (is_string($Options))
     $Options = array('LinkClass' => $Options);

  $LinkClass = GetValue('LinkClass', $Options, 'ProfileLink');
  $ImgClass = GetValue('ImageClass', $Options, 'ProfilePhotoMedium');

  $LinkClass = $LinkClass == '' ? '' : ' class="'.$LinkClass.'"';

  $Photo = $User->Photo;
  if (!$Photo && function_exists('UserPhotoDefaultUrl'))
     $Photo = UserPhotoDefaultUrl($User);

  if ($Photo) {
     if (!preg_match('`^https?://`i', $Photo)) {
        $PhotoUrl = Gdn_Upload::Url(ChangeBasename($Photo, 'n%s'));
     } else {
        $PhotoUrl = $Photo;
     }
     $Href = Url(UserUrl($User));
     return '<a title="'.htmlspecialchars($User->Name).'" href="'.$Href.'"'.$LinkClass.'>'
        .Img($PhotoUrl, array('alt' => htmlspecialchars($User->Name), 'class' => $ImgClass))
        .'</a>';
  } else {
     return '';
  }
```

}
}

Comment: How about modifying the line that generates it `$LinkClass = $LinkClass == '' ? '' : ' class="'.$LinkClass.' tip"';`?

Comment: I find the question hard to understand. Do you just mean you want to add " tip" (no quotes) to the variable `$LinkClass`? If so, that's easily accomplished doing `$LinkClass = $LinkClass == '' ? '' : ' class="'.$LinkClass.' tip"';` (Looks like zerkms beat me to it.)

Comment: Thats it boys thanks so much, I was adding it into the href link and not the var. Respect, many thanks to the person that got rid of the negative vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an array for the class attribute? Like this:

```
$LinkClass= array();
$LinkClassVal = GetValue('LinkClass', $Options, 'ProfileLink'); 

if($LinkClassVal){
    $LinkClass[] = $LinkClassVal;
}

$LinkClass[] = "tip";
```

and then on return :

```
return '<a title="'.htmlspecialchars($User->Name).'" href="'.$Href.'"'.implode(" ",$LinkClass).'>'
    .Img($PhotoUrl, array('alt' => htmlspecialchars($User->Name), 'class' => $ImgClass))
    .'</a>';
```

Comment: Yes, and you will have control whether you add or remove the class on specific conditions. Thanks for the upvote.